# Multiplication on the Schwartz space

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Is $(f,g)\mapsto fg: \mathcal{S}^2\to \mathcal{S}$ surjective?  Here, $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of complex-valued Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This question was asked and answered on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175092/given-a-schwartz-function-is-it-always-possible-to-write-it-as-a-product-of-two

Comment: Although product is surjective, interestingly, the squaring map is not surjective. The function $x^3 e^{-x^2}$ is not a square, because it vanishes to order 3 at 0, so it isn't the square of a smooth function, because 3 is not even. The $n$th power map is not surjective for similar reasons.